# Coloring certain sections of a barplot based on position in a matrix

Tags: r, colors, bar-chart

[My barplot as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRpIE.png)

This is a pretty straight-forward question, but I am struggling to find the code to do this task. I have four different breeding schemes set up here. I want the values [248:301] to be one color, [302:356] to be another, [357:428] another, and [429:500] to be a fourth color. What is the code for this in R (studio)?

```
u_pred <- bu_pred[248:500]
u_pred
barplot(u_pred, xlab = "Individual", ylab = "Breeding value")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `col` argument of `barplot` can take a vector. Example:

```
barplot(rnorm(100), col=c(rep('green', 50), rep('yellow', 50)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the rnorm bit messed it up for me, but the rest of the code worked beautifully, cheers!

Comment: The `rnorm` is just to generate some data, since I don't have your `bu_pred` data.